# How to ensure Java Web Start to download and install the lastest version

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have jdk 1.6 install on my machine but I want to run my code on JRE 1.7+ is there any method to ensure using JNLP that latest JRE will be automatically download and install?

Here is the current content of my JNLP file.

```
 <java  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"  version="1.7.0_17"  java-vm-args="-ea" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" />
```

I have also tried :

```
 <java  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"  version="1.7+"  java-vm-args="-ea" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" />
```

I am using direct proxy in my Java web start control panel and option to automatically download of JRE is enabled. But I am always getting a message to manually install JRE version and application stop. Please let me know if any further information is required. I do not wants my client to manually install the JRE. 
Operating System: Red hat Linux

JNLP file is verified using [JaneLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)

Comment: *"..is there any method to ensure using JNLP that latest JRE will be automatically download and install?"*  Why would the app. always require the latest Java version?  As a user, I often skip minor updates that are not security related.  +1 for validating the JNLP.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Let me rephrase it, I need to upgrade my application to use JRE 1.7 but my clients machine have JRE 1.6. I would not wants them to manually update their JRE so how can I enforce using JNLP to download and install JRE 1.7

Comment: I would first use the [deployment toolkit script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to ensure 1.7+ JRE (it will be executed before the JNLP is ever offered to the client).

Comment: Note that Oracle removed the JRE auto-download feature from Web Start in 2013: [openjdk bug 8006701](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8006701). Web Start now often (but not always) silently ignores the version specification.